# Output dimension of convolutional layer - where did color dimension go?

Tags: neural-networks, conv-neural-network

I'm working with a Convolutional Neural Network in Matlab, and I'm struggling to understand the output dimensionality of a convolutional layer.

The input is an image: `227 x 227 x 3` (last dimension is rgb). Filter size is `11 x 11`, and there are `96` filters. Vertical and horizontal stride is 4. There is no padding.

I tried calculating the output dimensionality as follows:

`output_width = (Width - FilterWidth + 2*Padding)/StrideHorizontal = (227 - 11 + 0)/4 = 55`.

Now, I expected an output of `55 x 55 x 3 x 96`, as there are `96` filters, but I get `55 x 55 x 96`.  What I don't understand is, what happened to the color dimension?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The filter dimension **replaces** the channels in the convolutional layer: $3$ **becomes** $96$ it isn't lost.

Each one of the pixels 96 in a specific location are computed as the **weighted average** of the $11\times11\times3$ pixels in the same region of the image.

For more details on how exactly the convolution operation is computed I'd suggest reading [this](https://cs231n.github.io/convolutional-networks/). It has numerical examples later on to see exactly what's computed.

Comment: Oooh, it's a weighted average. Thank you!